# CodeIgniter: routing & authentication

Tags: codeigniter, authentication, routes

The idea is to catch any access to controller's functions and, if we are authenticated, rout as normal and, if not, show the login form.

The question is, is **_remap** function the best place to check for access to controller's functions and how to pass routing back to CI in case we are authenticated?

Comment: do you want to authenticate user on each request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_remap` isn't necessary for this. You could use it, but you don't need to.

Check for access in the `__construct()` method of the controller. You can get the current method via `$this->router->fetch_method()` and authenticate against that.

Better yet, have all your controller that need this extend a base controller (aka "MY_Controller"). You can write an `Auth_Controller` and do the auth check in the `__construct()` there. You can get the current class via `$this->router->fetch_class()`, as well as the method, just make sure your controllers that need this extend `Auth_Controller` instead of the usual `CI_Controller`.

If they shouldn't have access, just redirect them where they need to go or show an error.

Comment: No problem -  I was going to post examples but it sounds like you know what you're doing. Does this make sense or is anything unclear?

Answer (score 1):

make a library called `Authentication` and check about your method in this

you can get method and class name by this

```
$class = $this->CI->router->class;
$method = $this->CI->router->method;
```

and to check this authentication each time you have enabled the `hooks` from your config file, attach a `post_controller_constructor` hook to check authentication each time.